# Content database on SharePoint 2016 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to know if it is possible  to create content Database on SharePoint 2016 Online, and how can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No... you can’t create content database in Sharepoint online

Reason being SPO is cloud SAAS service and you won’t have control over which site collection goes where. Internally it will create content database for site collection you create or store it in already created dB.

Not sure why you need it...if you can explain reason behind doing this there might another way of what you want to achieve

Comment: thank you for response, i don't have reason i juste ask, i'm beginner on sharepoint

Comment: Asking is good ..please mark it answer for others reference..